# How to programmatically Download a file from Google Drive, using Javascript and HTML? (NOT Google Drive API)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-shared-drive

**Goal:**

1. In my Chrome Browser, open this [Public Google Drive Folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-59RzLYkWDmS5NGtNNMZpzRhh8z0zICP?usp=share_link)
2. Then run a javascript to:

- **Select** the first file in the Google Drive folder
- **Download** it

**P.S:** I do NOT want to use the GoogleDriveAPI.

**Steps:**

**1.** Select file

**2.** Download file, using one of the following options:

- Click Download button from page *(top left - appears when file is selected)*
- Expand the file options menu *(three dots top right of each file)* and click the Download button from the dropdown menu

**What's working:**

Select the file using:

```
document.querySelector('div[jsname=LvFR7c]').click()
```

Expand the file options menu using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pc7nUb I5YcP Dk9rmd").click()
```

**What's NOT working:**

Clicking Download button from page or from file options menu

**Conclusion:**

I noticed that the Google Drive HTML elements are mostly  with aria roles like **button**, **menu**, & **menuitem**. Some of these elements have a **jsaction** attribute. When these elements are clicked via code, some of them behave as they do when clicking with the mouse, and others do nothing when clicked via code. So I'm just confused and am not sure what to try next.

I feel like this is a trivial task, but this is my first time working in Javascript & HTML, so I'm sure I might be missing something simple.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Download Button HTML Elements:**

Page Download button HTML:

```
document.querySelector('div[aria-label=Download]')
```

File Options Menu Download button HTML:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[aria-label=Download]')[3]
```

**Things I've tried on the above *Download Button HTML Elements*:**

```
element.click()
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown')) // (with more options in the Event initializer)
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'))
element.focus()
element.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true)
element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', true)
element.ariaPressed = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way as below:

### Steps:

1. Find unique id of images

   ```
   let imgDiv = document.querySelectorAll('c-wiz>div[data-id]');
   var imgIds = [];
   imgNodes.forEach(img => {
       let imgId = img.getAttribute('data-id');
       // console.log(imgId);
       imgIds.push(imgId);
   });
   ```
2. use `fetch` api to if you want to show as blob url, otherwise open url in new tab as below

   ```
   // imgIds[0] = 1-XLXQ04HZtNmPgC-zpYnQEDq3w5aPlDR
   let downloadLink = `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${imgIds[0]}`;
   window.open(downloadLink, '_blank');
   ```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! I'm accepting the answer since it addresses the original download issue.

And while that works perfectly for downloading, I was curious how I would interact with/click the aforementioned HTML elements, in case I wanted to do other things like 'Add to starred', 'Delete', 'Make a Copy', etc... 
I'm also curious, what is fetch api and blob url, and how would I use them in this case?

Thank you!